# Error Finding App Store Connect Credentials

Tags: xcode

Getting the error below when trying to validate/distribute to Apple Store from Xcode
[image]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just go to XCode settings and sign in again under Accounts tab
[image]

Comment: Tried this.  Still seeing error.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 41):

I also got this. I followed Alex's own answer but it didn't worked (and I wasn't signed off).

I just quit Xcode and opened again.

Comment: The problem for me was because I was signed off. It seems that the root cause of the problem for you is different.

Comment: For me, rebooting my MacBook works...

Comment: I thought my client removed my account :( 
This saved me.

Comment: This magical piece of Xcode software never stops amazing me

Answer (score 9):

Just quit xcode and open again worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Open Safari browser, sign in to appstoreconnect.apple.com and retry distribute app. You will get this error, if not signed in.

Answer (score 2):

I just quit Xcode and opened Xcode again.
its works for me the root cause is if you are working with VPN and agin changing your network preference as open network. or vice-versa this kind of problem will come.
So just try quit Xcode and clean the build and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You logged out Apple Account in XCode. Login account again and restart Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was on a VNC session and had to first run:

> security unlock-keychain login.keychain